# Can't copy XML on Clickonce deployment

Tags: c#, dll, clickonce

I have a solution with 2 projects:

```
  MainSolution
     Project A
     Project B
       Folder A
         Settings.xml (Embedded R.->Copy Always)
```

But when I try to deploy it over ClickOnce, I got an error when the app starts, something like: "Could not find the .xml file", so the problem is basically that in the deployment part the file is not copied over the output directory.

I tried to:

*Change the output dir from my project B to the bin\debug in project A
*I included my project B as required in the app files for project A in the publish setting of my main project (Project A).

PS: The error is obtained when I tried to retrieve my settings in the fiel, I tried to use:

*Application.StartupPath + "\Folder\Settings.xml
*Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName) + "\Project B\Folder\Settings.xml"

Thanks, regards.

Comment: Is both Project A & B exe?  Or is one of them DLL project?

Comment: Project A = WinForm App Project and B is DLL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "Project B" folder.  When the application is deployed, everything would be in the "Project A' folder.  Also, you have indicated that "settings.xml" file is an "Embedded Resource".  Therefore that resource will be available via [Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt(v=vs.110).aspx).